# How to animate this Cable?

Tags: animation, bones, bezier-curves, weight-painting

So, I have a chain to be animated in blender. I animated the chain using curves, but to export to unity, it needs to be in a .abc format which is too huge(files coming up to even 1 GB). Can anyone tell me how to export the curve animations to an fbx format?

Also if possible, can anyone tell me how to animate the chains using rigs?[image: Here's a picture of the chain to be animated]